# fs.exists not accepting variables

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I'm using post requests to search for binaries but can't get the following code to work correctly. fs.exists() won't accept the variable b_path but will work correctly if given a hard coded string. b_path prints to the console as expected, correctly building the path to the binary.

```
app.post('*', function(req, res) {

  // generate the name of the binary
  var request = require('url').parse(req.url, true);
  var len = request.pathname.toString().length;

  var binary = request.pathname.slice(1,len);
  binary = binary.concat(' ');

  var b_path = app.get('binaries_path')+binary;

  fs.exists(b_path, function (exists) {
    if(exists) {
      console.log('exists');
    }
  }
}
```

Why does this occur?

Comment: The function accepts variables or literals just the same.  `b_path` must not be correct.  What's with the `concat(' ')`?  The files you're looking for have spaces on the end?  That might be the discrepancy with what you think you see in the console output, if the files do not actually have spaces at the end.

Comment: Cheers guys, it was the concat function, i needed it for something else but now realise it doesn't need to be there. Where's this green checkmark?

Comment: The accept check mark is below the up/down vote arrows to the left of each answer.